# How to use a list of values as indexes on a matrix?

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a simple matrix (accessed through X2[,take[conval]] because it's a subset of an original one) made like this

> ```
> Names             ColA                  ColB                ColC
> 338               0.03125               0.31250             0.03125
> 339               0.03125               0.31250             0.03125
> 518               0.03125               0.43750             0.06250
> 561               0.03125               0.03125             0.68750
> 562               0.03125               0.03125             0.68750
> ```

I have then created a list "indexes" with all the indexes I need to retain

> ```
> $colA
> 338 339 518 561 562 
>   1   2   3   4   5 
>
> $colB
> 561 562 
>   4   5 
>
> $colC
> 338 339 
>   1   2
> ```

I need now to select just the values pointed by the inxes for further calculations. I do not want to use another for loop since I am already inside one and the program will be likely to run very slowly. I tried to implement something like

```
X2[,take[conval]][indexes]
```

or

```
sapply(X2[,take[conval]],"[",indexes)
```

But obviously it does not work since indexes is a list.
Long story short I need to select all the elements from the first column,last two from the second and first two from the third without a for loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Names             ColA                  ColB                ColC
338               0.03125               0.31250             0.03125
339               0.03125               0.31250             0.03125
518               0.03125               0.43750             0.06250
561               0.03125               0.03125             0.68750
562               0.03125               0.03125             0.68750")

mm <- as.matrix(dd)
l <- list(ColA = 1:5, ColB = 4:5, ColC = 1:2)

lapply(names(l), function(x) mm[l[[x]], x])

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.03125 0.03125
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.03125 0.03125
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Map(`[`, X2[-1], indexes)
#$ColA
#[1] 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125

#$ColB
#[1] 0.03125 0.03125

#$ColC
#[1] 0.03125 0.03125
```

NOTE: I assumed that the dataset is `data.frame`.  If it is a matrix, then convert to `data.frame`

```
Map(`[`, as.data.frame(X2[,-1]), indexes)
```

If you wish to get the elements in a `vector`, another option is

```
 X2[,-1][as.matrix(transform(stack(indexes), 
                ind=as.numeric(factor(ind))))]
 #[1] 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125
```

#### data

```
X2 <- structure(list(Names = c(338L, 339L, 518L, 561L, 562L),
ColA = c(0.03125, 
0.03125, 0.03125, 0.03125, 0.03125), ColB = c(0.3125, 0.3125, 
0.4375, 0.03125, 0.03125), ColC = c(0.03125, 0.03125, 0.0625, 
0.6875, 0.6875)), .Names = c("Names", "ColA", "ColB", "ColC"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

indexes <- structure(list(colA = structure(1:5,
.Names = c("338", "339", 
"518", "561", "562")), colB = structure(c(4, 5), .Names = c("561", 
"562")), colC = structure(c(1, 2), .Names = c("338", "339"))),
.Names = c("colA", "colB", "colC"))
```